# How can I get list of people who satisfies several requirements from different tables?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make

```
SELECT user_id
     , field_id
     , field_value 
  FROM xf_user_field_value 
 WHERE field_id = 'isAccepted' 
    OR field_id = 'isTested'
```

this one work only if user_group_id from user_id is 2

```
SELECT user_id
  FROM xf_user
 WHERE user_group_id = 2
```

But I wasnt able to connect these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT xf_user.username
     , xf_user_field_value.user_id
     , xf_user_field_value.field_id
     , xf_user_field_value.field_value 
FROM xf_user INNER JOIN xf_user_field_value 
  ON xf_user.user_id = xf_user_field_value.user_id 
WHERE (xf_user_field_value.field_id = 'isAccepted' OR
       xf_user_field_value.field_id = 'isTested')
  AND xf_user.user_group_id = 2
```